# Kibana for MySql

Tags: mysql, kibana

We are very satisfied with Kibana over ElasticSearch.

Since we do more of statistical analysis, we were thinking that MySql might be a better choice for us.

Is there a Kibana alternative to work with MySql?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** This product doesn't seem to be available anymore.

---

You should take a look at [FnordMetric](http://fnordmetric.io/):

> FnordMetric allows you to write SQL queries that return SVG charts rather than tables. Turning a query result into a chart is literally one line of code

By using their SQL based dialect, you can write queries that generates elegant graphs and use them build analytics dashboards.

[FnordMetric Server](http://fnordmetric.io/documentation/getting_started/fnordmetric-server/) Supports MySQL as a data source, among others.

While this is not as mature a product as Kibana, it seems to fit well with your use case.

If you are looking for something more sophisticated perhaps you should take a look at BI tools like [Looker](http://www.looker.com/product)

Answer (score 1):

You should a have look on [Open source Alternative Kibi](https://siren.solutions/kibi/)
It works well with both Elastic Search as well as MySQL. I think it will be very useful for you.

***PS: Not linked to Kibi in any way***

Answer (score 0):

try grafana. its like kibana but has support for other data source such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, Graphite etc. https://grafana.com/